# Use of Semicolon in this sentence and way of spliting it

Tags: semicolons

Want to know the specific meaning of the two semicolons in the sentence below.
And is there any good idea to split this sentence using appropriate transitions?

> The fundamental insight into the necessity of the return to
> consciousness; the radical and explicit determination of the path of,
> and the procedural rules for, this return; the principle-based
> determination and systematic exploration of the field that is to be
> disclosed11 in this return -- this we designate as phenomenology.

Comment: Note that the second item in the list of three contains two parenthetical-offsetting commas. The writer is using the option of using semicolons as 'super-commas' rather than true semicolons. many accept this practice, some don't. // Bullet points are almost always clearer, but unacceptable in some arenas.

Comment: The Lexico guide [How to use a semicolon](https://www.lexico.com/grammar/semicolon) explains the usage.

Comment: This is a good example of what newspapers call burying the lead. If phenomenology has three parts, tell me that at the top, then list them in the next sentence. The semicolons make for a long sentence that is hard to process on first read.